# Django Template - neat 1-1 translation of values (dictionary lookup)

Tags: python, css, django

I've an object containing an attribute defined by a series of choices - here's it's class definition:

```
class StashURLJobRequest(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = ((0,"Requested"),(1,"Done"),(2,"Failed"))
    url = models.URLField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now=False)
    processed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = False, auto_now = True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=(STATUS_CHOICES))
    requestBy = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(self.url + str(self.created))
    def status_display(self):
        status_dict = dict(self.STATUS_CHOICES)
        return status_dict[self.status]
```

I get a list of these and pass through into a template, intending to render each one as an individual row, again, here's the template code:

```
  {% for job_instance in jobs %}

  <div class="width100pc">
    <div class="width10pc"> <img src="{% static 'img/empty.png' %}" /> </div>
    <div class="width80pc">
    <div class="width70pc textleft sans textsmall "> <a href="{{ job_instance.url }}" target="_blank">{{ job_instance.url }}</a> </div>
    <div class="width15pc textcentre sans texttiny "> {{ job_instance.processed }} </div>
    <div class="width5pc textcentre sans texttiny {% ifequal job_instance.status_display 'Done' %} status_green {% endifequal %}
                                                  {% ifequal job_instance.status_display 'Requested' %} status_amber {% endifequal %}
                                                   {% ifequal job_instance.status_display 'Failed' %} status_red {% endifequal %}"> {{ job_instance.status_display }} </div>
        <div class="width10pc textcentre sans texttiny"> {{ job_instance.requestBy }} </div>
    </div>
    <div class="width10pc"> <img src="{% static 'img/empty.png' %}" /> </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

In particular, note the section:

```
{% ifequal job_instance.status_display 'Done' %} status_green {% endifequal %}
{% ifequal job_instance.status_display 'Requested' %} status_amber {% endifequal %}
{% ifequal job_instance.status_display 'Failed' %} status_red {% endifequal %}
```

Each of {status_green, status_amber and status_red} refer to a different css class, and allows me to render the status in an appropriate colour.

This seems a little unwieldy, and I don't want to code the css-class into the model, or the view (preferring to leave format and display to the template/html definitions) - so the question is, is there a way to do this that's more "pythonic" - ideally, I'd like to use something like:

```
{{ class_dict = {'Done' : 'status_green', 'Requested' : 'status_amber', 'Failed' : 'status_red' } }}

< ... some code ... >

{{ class_dict[job_instance.status_display] }}
```

(dodgy curly-braces aside!)

Answer (score 1):

Add a helper function to the object, so that you don't need any logic in the template?

Add to StashURLJobRequest

```
def status_display_colour(self): 
  return {
    "Done":"status_green", 
    "Requested":"status_amber", 
    "Failed":"status_red"
         }[ self.status_display() ]
```

And the template becomes `<div class="width5pc textcentre sans texttiny {{ job_instance.status_display_colour }} ...`

Another way would be `class="... my-class-{{job_instance.status_display}}"` with my-class-Done, my-class-Requested, my-class-Failed appropriately defined in your css. It's inferior because it depends implicitly on status_display remaining a single word with no spaces or other special characters.